# Error using dynamic nonce in .htaccess Content-Security-Policy (CSP) and PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, meta-tags, nonce

I know this has been asked countless times, but I cant seem to find a solution to my problem.

The Problem : I am unable to use Content-Security-Policy nonce and its generating an error.

The Error via console.log : Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-eM7IckhPhRx5dBGXZhwsgAKulpq/euetK0YPweqUKX4='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note that hashes do not apply to event handlers, style attributes and javascript: navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present. Note also that 'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

What I also tried : I also tried using mod_unique_id instead of using PHP set env but it throws internal server error

What am i doing wrong

My Code :

.htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
FileETag None
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
Header set Connection keep-alive
Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"

SetEnv MY_CSP_NONCE "<?php echo $_SERVER['MY_CSP_NONCE']; ?>"

Header always set Content-Security-Policy "expr=default-src 'none'; script-src 'self' require-trusted-types-for 'script' https://www.googletagmanager.com https://www.facebook.com https://www.twitter.com https://www.instagram.com 'nonce-%{ENV:MY_CSP_NONCE}' 'strict-dynamic' 'wasm-eval' 'unsafe-eval'; script-src-elem 'self'; connect-src 'self'; img-src 'self' https://storage.googleapis.com data:; video-src 'self' https://storage.googleapis.com data:; style-src 'self' style-src-attr 'self' 'nonce-%{ENV:MY_CSP_NONCE}'; base-uri 'none'; object-src 'none'; frame-ancestors 'self'; frame-src 'self'; sandbox allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups; media-src 'self'; worker-src 'self https://*.cloudflare.com'; manifest-src 'self'; child-src 'self'; prefetch-src 'self' https://storage.googleapis.com https://www.googletagmanager.com; form-action 'self' https://www.paystack.com; font-src 'self' data:; upgrade-insecure-requests"

Header set Feature-Policy "geolocation 'self'; vibrate 'none'"
Header always set Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only "default-src 'self'; report-uri https://www.example.com/csp-report-endpoint"
Header always set X-Frame-Options "sameorigin"
Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains; preload"
Header always set Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy "same-origin-allow-popups"
Header always set Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy "same-site"
SetEnvIf Referer "^https://storage.googleapis.com" CORP_EXEMPT
Header always set Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy "require-same-origin"
Header always set Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy "unsafe-none" env=CORP_EXEMPT
Header set Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy "unsafe-none" "expr=%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m!\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|webp|avif|mp4|webm|m4a|ogv)$!"
</IfModule>

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^index$ ./index.php
RewriteRule ^about$ ./about.php

RewriteRule ^404$ ./404.php
RewriteRule ^500$ ./500.php

ErrorDocument 404 https://www.example.com/404

IndexIgnore *
```

my cookiesetter.php - Where nonce is stored to be included in every script

```
  <?php 
  $nonce = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode(random_bytes(64)), '+/', '-_'), '=');
  putenv("MY_CSP_NONCE=$nonce");
  ?>
```

and index.php

```
  <?php include "cookiesetter.php" ?>

  <html>
  <head>
  <title>Example</title>
  <style nonce="<?php echo $nonce ?>">
  bla bla bla
  </style>
  </head>

  <body>
  <script nonce="<?php echo $nonce ?>">
  bla bla bla
  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: `SetEnv MY_CSP_NONCE "<?php echo $_SERVER['MY_CSP_NONCE']; ?>"` - you expect PHP code to be executed _inside your .htaccess_ ...?

Comment: it cant execute, thats why i am asking what to do to solve the problem, thats what i tried how can I solve the problem. Do you know how to?

Comment: Set that header from _within_ your actual PHP scripts instead, using https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php ...?

Comment: @CBroe ok thanks, but how do i reference it in .htaccess so it know that nonce is been used to allow it.

Comment: @Shasha the actual Content-Security-Policy header should be set from within PHP dynamically, you can't make it dynamic in Apache like this.

Comment: @soulseekah thanks for your response, please could you give an example, on the answer section, been trying to solve this problem, in the lasdt 4 days and its been driving me nuts, i dont know how to do it, if i comment that line my site works perfectly. Use the example i gave PLEASE

Comment: @Sasha you should do `header( 'Content-Security-Policy: ....` in your cookiesetter.php file. Do note that multiple CSP headers are not permitted, there has to be one CSP header value with everything you need for the page. So you'll have to remove the Header from .htaccess and only send it from within PHP.

Comment: @soulseekah okay

Answer (score 0):

So i solved it with the help of @soulseekah and another online friend.

The solution

.htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
FileETag None
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
Header set Connection keep-alive
Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"

#comment #OUT just for REFERENCE PURPOSES #SetEnv MY_CSP_NONCE "<?php echo $_SERVER['MY_CSP_NONCE']; ?>"
#commented #OUT just for REFERENCE PURPOSES #Header always set Content-Security-Policy "expr=default-src 'none'; script-src 'self' require-trusted-types-for 'script' https://www.googletagmanager.com https://www.facebook.com https://www.twitter.com https://www.instagram.com 'nonce-%{ENV:MY_CSP_NONCE}' 'strict-dynamic' 'wasm-eval' 'unsafe-eval'; script-src-elem 'self'; connect-src 'self'; img-src 'self' https://storage.googleapis.com data:; video-src 'self' https://storage.googleapis.com data:; style-src 'self' style-src-attr 'self' 'nonce-%{ENV:MY_CSP_NONCE}'; base-uri 'none'; object-src 'none'; frame-ancestors 'self'; frame-src 'self'; sandbox allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups; media-src 'self'; worker-src 'self https://*.cloudflare.com'; manifest-src 'self' https://storage.googleapis.com data:; child-src 'self'; prefetch-src 'self' https://storage.googleapis.com https://www.googletagmanager.com; form-action 'self' https://www.paystack.com; font-src 'self' data:; upgrade-insecure-requests"

<Files "cookiesetter.php">
<If "-f %{REQUEST_FILENAME}">
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "none"
</If>
</Files>

Header set Feature-Policy "geolocation 'self'; vibrate 'none'"
Header always set Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only "default-src 'self'; report-uri https://www.example.com/csp-report-endpoint"
Header always set X-Frame-Options "sameorigin"
Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains; preload"
Header always set Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy "same-origin-allow-popups"
Header always set Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy "same-site"
SetEnvIf Referer "^https://storage.googleapis.com" CORP_EXEMPT
Header always set Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy "require-same-origin"
Header always set Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy "unsafe-none" env=CORP_EXEMPT
Header set Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy "unsafe-none" "expr=%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m!\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|webp|avif|mp4|webm|m4a|ogv)$!"
</IfModule>

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^index$ ./index.php
RewriteRule ^about$ ./about.php

RewriteRule ^404$ ./404.php
RewriteRule ^500$ ./500.php

ErrorDocument 404 https://www.example.com/404

IndexIgnore *
```

my cookiesetter.php - Where nonce is stored to be included in every script

```
<?php 
$nonce = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode(random_bytes(64)), '+/', '-_'), '=');
$cspHeader = "expr=default-src 'none'; script-src 'self' https://www.googletagmanager.com https://www.facebook.com https://www.twitter.com https://www.instagram.com; nonce-$nonce 'strict-dynamic' 'wasm-eval' 'unsafe-eval'; script-src-elem 'self'; connect-src 'self'; img-src 'self' https://storage.googleapis.com data:; video-src 'self' https://storage.googleapis.com data:; style-src 'self' style-src-attr 'self' 'nonce-$nonce'; base-uri 'none'; object-src 'none'; frame-ancestors 'self'; frame-src 'self'; sandbox allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups; media-src 'self'; worker-src 'self https://*.cloudflare.com'; manifest-src 'self' https://www.googletagmanager.com https://storage.googleapis.com; child-src 'self'; prefetch-src 'self' https://storage.googleapis.com https://www.googletagmanager.com; form-action 'self' https://www.paystack.com; font-src 'self' data:; upgrade-insecure-requests";
header("Content-Security-Policy: $cspHeader");
?>
```

and index.php

```
 <?php include "cookiesetter.php" ?>

  <html>
  <head>
  <title>Example</title>
  <style nonce="<?php echo $nonce ?>">
  bla bla bla
  </style>
  </head>

  <body>
  <script nonce="<?php echo $nonce ?>">
  bla bla bla
  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Guys please feel free to add an edit what you think. Edit my answer and add yours even if it is in 10 years time.

This is a learning platform.